# Is there a simpler version of WP Media?

Tags: custom-field, uploads

I'm developing a plugin where users need to be able to upload an image (a payment receipt) to a custom user field. At the time, I'm using a code I found here [Extra User Profile Field Upload File / Image](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53902/extra-user-profile-field-upload-file-image) and it is working. The problem is I don't want WP Media to show a lot of things, I just want the user to be able to upload a single image without seeing private site information or media and without being able to create something like a gallery.

Please, answer if you have any idea about how doing it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) to do this.

1. Set up your custom field for the user profile.
2. Use the [acf_form()](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf_form/) to produce a form containing the field on your front end for the user to interact with.
3. Customise your acf_form() arguments to use a "simple" uploader (this will not expose WP Media Library to users then)

Example:

```
$field_arguments = array(
  'post_id' => 'user_'.$current_user->ID,
  'field_groups' => array(111), // Replace with ACF Group you created
  'form' => true,
  'uploader' => 'basic', // This is what hides the WP Media Library to the user
  'submit_value'    => 'Submit'
);
```

Comment: It works for me, thank you so much